# Ubuntu 14.04 realtime kernels = 3.13

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati

I use OpenGL 4.4 drivers with ATI drivers (only for kernel 3.13)

**System Requirements for opengl 4.4**:

```
Xorg/Xserver 7.4 and above (up to 1.15)
Linux kernel 2.6 or above (up to 3.13)
glibc version 2.2 or 2.3
POSIX Shared Memory (/dev/shm) support is required for 3D applications.
```

And now i use `3.13.30-lowlanency kernel`, and i am not found realtime kernel.
Give me link or source realtime kernel 3.13 thx.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/linux-image-3.13.0-32-lowlatency/

I am looking for real time kernel

Answer (score 2):

sorry there isn't any, because linux-rt project was ended at Lucid(10.04)

Comment: Because RT was merged into the main kernel I believe.

Comment: nopes RT isn't merged with main kernel. As RT project meant for Ubuntu Studio, but they stick to low latency kernel. Currently with Ubuntu support best near to RT kernel is low latency kernel.